# Android preferences issue

Tags: java, android, preferences, securityexception

I'm trying to make a preference screen for my android application, but I'm failing completely. I'm following [this guide](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html). When I try to install the application, I get this error message, and it won't install the app on my phone:

```
[2012-04-10 12:54:45 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ------------------------------
[2012-04-10 12:54:45 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] Android Launch!
[2012-04-10 12:54:45 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-10 12:54:45 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] Performing ValutaConverter.namespace.AndroidValutaConverterActivity activity launch
[2012-04-10 12:54:45 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] Automatic Target Mode: using device '3134BC2BBCA800EC'
[2012-04-10 12:54:45 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] Uploading AndroidCurrencyConverter.apk onto device '3134BC2BBCA800EC'
[2012-04-10 12:54:46 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] Installing AndroidCurrencyConverter.apk...
[2012-04-10 12:54:49 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] Success!
[2012-04-10 12:54:49 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] Starting activity ValutaConverter.namespace.AndroidValutaConverterActivity on device 3134BC2BBCA800EC
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=ValutaConverter.namespace/.AndroidValutaConverterActivity }
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=ValutaConverter.namespace/.AndroidValutaConverterActivity } from null (pid=11486, uid=2000) requires android.permission.INTERNET
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1631)
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:433)
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:107)
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:80)
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.finishInit(Native Method)
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:238)
[2012-04-10 12:54:52 - AndroidCurrencyConverter] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I understood from this code was that when it tries to start the Intent, it fails because it requires android.permission.INTERNET. But this is already defined in my manifest file.

I had the app working at some point, but I added a few things to my activity, added another activity, and some XML files. After this, it won't install the app on the phone. What I added was:

In the activity class:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Show current settings");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ShowSettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you need any other information about the code or the likes of that, I will gladly post some of it.

Help!

Comment: Please add the contents of your manifest file

Comment: [Here is the code for the manifest file](http://pastie.org/3761284)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be,

```
<uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AndroidValutaConverterActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShowSettingsActivity"/>
</application>
```

remove it from activity tag in your manifest file.

Comment: Alright. I used that as my manifest file, but now the application just stops working when I try to install it. I get a Fatal Exception: Main.

Comment: Is your AndroidValutaConverterActivity extend ListActivity?

Comment: No, it extends PreferenceActivity.

Comment: Any other activity which extend ListActivity in your application?

Comment: No, they extend PreferenceActivity, PreferenceActivity (unused class) and Activity. None that extend ListActivity.

Comment: With the new error log and code of AndroidValutaConverterActivity post new question it a issues with listview id ('android.R.id.list').

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, but your are not *allowing* the INTERNET permission in the manifest (instead, you explictely say that the activity *requires* the INTERNET permission).

You should have a [`<permission>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) at the root of the manifest, as explained in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check.

1. Your activity is extending PreferenceActivity, and
2. That your layout has a default ListView with the id android:list

   ```
   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   ```

Also you may want to think about implementing OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in your activity if you need to  handle preference changes.